# Git flow with Bitbucket pull requests

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow, pull-request

I used `git flow feature finish` to finish a feature branch. I use the AVH fork of git-flow, which deletes the remote feature branch - but the Bitbucket pull request is still open. How should I close the Bitbucket pull request?

And what is a correct way to accept a PR in future while following the git flow workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the AVH version of git-flow deletes the remote feature branch when you do `git flow feature finish`, strangely, it doesn't push anything. It leaves you on the master branch, so once you've done `git push` or `git push origin master:master`, the BitBucket pull request will automatically be marked as merged, which closes it. It is not necessary to amend the commit message - it works with the standard commit message.

Answer (score 0):

The AVH version of git-flow has some additional features:
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh

It has support for hooks (custom scripts):
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-Hooks-and-Filters#hooks

You can swap to the AVH version on a Mac using:

```
brew uninstall git-flow
brew install git-flow-avh
```

To support a pull request in git flow you can add a script:

```
.git/hooks/post-flow-feature-publish.sh
```

When running the command:

```
git flow feature my-feature publish
```

Git flow will push code to the feature branch and call the hook script to create the PR.

Comment: thanks for this but where can we find the post-flow-feature-publish.sh ? not everyone is familiar with the Github or Bitbucket API

Comment: The script has to be written, I'm not aware of any open-source versions. But there should be!