# How can we update Bitbucket PR status as merged, if we merge the branch using git command line tools and delete feature branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let us consider this scenario, a PR has been initiated for a branch my-fea-branch1. Then whatever the reason the changes from this branch has been merged to the master branch by using git command line tool. Then delete the branch too by using git command line tool. Currently Bitbucket is not able to automatically detect the workflow and once it realize the branch has deleted it is marking the PR as DECLINED. In short the step summer is.

```bash
# Bitbucket PR has opened for my-fea-branch1

git switch master
git merge --squash my-fea-branch1

git add -A
git commit -m "some comment"
git push origin master

git push origin --delete  my-fea-branch1

# By then bitbucket marks the PR state to DECLINED.
```

Comment: What happens if you push without the `--delete`?

Comment: Yes, I was pushing the change to master first then deleting the feature branch, just updated all steps in the original posting.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381449/184546), if you push `feature` first, and then push `master` with `feature` merged, the PR will be marked as "Merged". If you reverse the order it will be marked "Declined". I suspect if you delete your feature branch it is also marked "Declined".

Comment: Thanks TTT, not sure how we can send changes to feature branch, the squashed changes are on top of master. I tried pushing to master and then merge master on top of feature that did not work.